# Flutter Firestore, interacting with user?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Flutter: I'm using Streambuilder to listen to Firestore data which works great.

However, what I would like to do is to notify the user when certain conditions in Firestore changes, let him respond and write that back to Firestore.

Doable (in Flutter/Dart)?

Thanks in advance.

Best,
/j

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
    List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.documents;
    documents.forEach((doc) {
        if (doc['Invited']) {
            **// notify current user that he is invited, 
            // let him reply yes/no, write that value back to Firestore**
        }
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Yes, it's doable, but don't expect ready-to-use code. There are lots of tutorials out there how to use Firestore and Flutter.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply.

Care to point me in the right direction? Again, using Streambuilder and listening to changes (and displaying them) isn't the problem. 

The problem is to notify the user and let him respond back. 

Best,
/j

Comment: "The problem is to notify the user and let him respond back." that's quite unspecific. You can for example use a https://flutter.io/cookbook/design/snackbars/

Comment: Thanks again, really appreciate it. I think the problem is more logical/structural. Here's the code: `StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
 List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.documents;
 documents.forEach((doc) {
  if (doc['Invited']) {
   // notify current user that he is invited, 
   // let him reply yes/no, write that value back to Firestore
  }
 }
  },
);`

Comment: Please add the code to the question (properly formatted). Longer code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Argh, my bad. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a point why you dont want to use [Firebase Messaging](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging)?

1) Firestore triggers a Notification

2) Your App recieve the notification

3) Your app handle the notification, it should be possible that the user dont see the notification in the status bar.

Comment: Thanks. Well, no, but if possible I would like to do it without plugins. But thanks, I will take a look if nothing else works.

Comment: You are welcome, it would be helpful when you add this to your question otherwise you maybe get more solutions with plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to update something as soon as the user receives an invitation. You can do this by using code like this:

```
Future<Null> updateUser{
  @required String userId,
  bool accepted,
}) {
  assert(userId != null && userId.isNotEmpty);

  // create map that contains all fields to update
  Map<String, dynamic> dataToUpdate = {
      "accepted": accepted,
  };

  // get the reference to the user you want to update
  final userRef = references.users(userId);

  // update the user
  return userRef.updateData(dataToUpdate);
}
```

You can get the reference from your document by using **doc.reference**. The Future will complete if the update was successful or terminate with an error if something went wrong.